# jQuery DataTables columnDefs based on if condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

In DataTables, in the columnDefs, can we do if condition statement? Based on variable value, we decide which column to show / hide below.
How do I solve the below issue?
The below code throws this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if

```
"columnDefs": [
        if (operation == Operation.VIEW) {
            {"targets": [0], "className": "text-center"},
            {"targets": [1], "className": "text-center"},
            {"targets": [2], "width": "3%", "visible": false}
        }
        if (operation == Operation.EDIT) {
            {"targets": [0], "className": "text-center"},
            {"targets": [1], "width": "3%", "visible": false},
            {"targets": [2], "className": "text-center"}
        }
    ],
```

Comment: You could instead call a function in which you could check the condition and return the respective object instead. what you have done is added a condition inside an array. which is not expected.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below syntax and code to implement your logic

```
"columnDefs" : [ {
                            "targets" : [ 3, 4, 5 ],
                            render : function(data, type, row, meta) {
                                if (meta.col == 4) {
                                    if (data == 1) {
                                        return 'Test1';
                                    } else if (data == 2) {
                                        return 'Test2';
                                    }
                                } else if (meta.col == 3 || meta.col == 5) {

                                    if (data == null || data == "") {
                                        return "";
                                    } else {
                                        return data;
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                        } ],


"columnDefs" : [ {
                            "className" : "dt-center",
                            "targets" : "0"
                        } ],
```